# How can I specify a type of "hex color code" in flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm using flow and React and I want to have a type that represents a string of length either 4 or 7, only using the letters a-f, and that starts with a "#".

Does flow even support those kinds of types?

Comment: Wouldn't the length be 4 or 7?

Comment: You're right. I edited the post to reflect that.